# How do I do subgrouping in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I have this data set:

```
id   city   result fruit
1    boston good   apple
2    boston bad    banana
3    ny     good   peach
4    ny     good   banana
5    ny     good   apple
6    ny     bad    apple
...
```

So imagine that this data set goes on and has results for any number of fruit and any number of cities.
The problem is, I don't know how to perform a query to give me results like this:

```
city   fruit   good   bad
ny     bananna 3      2
ny     apple   1      3
ny     peach   3      2
boston banana  2      5
boston peach   2      1
...
```

The idea is that we are grouping by two things, the city and the fruit, but I want to get only the count of fruit within each city.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This technique is generally called a "pivot":

```
select
    city,
    fruit,
    sum(result = 'good') as good,
    sum(result = 'bad') as bad
from mytable
group by 1,2
```

Notice the elegant use of `sum(condition)` rather than the mundane `sum(case...)`

#### Edited

As usual, people can't help but make critical/irrelevant comments, so for the record...

The `sum(condition)` approach works for any database that treats `true` as `1` and `false` as `0`. Mysql is one such database, thus this is an appropriate answer for a `mysql` tagged question. Mileage may vary with other databases.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler This question was tagged `mysql`, so your comment is irrelevant.

Comment: The question is tagged SQL so my comment is relevant to anyone reading the answer with a view to applying it to any other DBMS.  Also, my comment was not critical in the sense of implying your answer is wrong (it is OK given that the question is tagged MySQL); it was observing that MySQL is different from most other DBMS in allowing this usage, and that most other DBMS will not allow you to that.

Answer (score 2):

You are pivotting your data. The simplest way I know of in this case is to

- `GROUP` on the `city` and `fruit` columns
- Use a `CASE` to determine if a record accounts for good or bad
- `SUM` these results

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT city
       , fruit
       , SUM(CASE WHEN result = 'good' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS good
       , SUM(CASE WHEN result = 'bad' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bad
FROM   Fruits
GROUP BY
       city
       , fruit
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT City, Fruit,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 'good' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Good,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 'good' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS Bad
  FROM DataSet
 GROUP BY City, Fruit
```